# WebExtension: set width for options UI

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm adding an HTML page with options to my webextension. On Firefox it looks something like this:

[image: firefox options page]

On Chrome, I get this layout:

[image: chrome options page]

As you can see, in Chrome the HTML is embedded in a kind of popup. The width of this popup is too small to display the content properly.

For some reason, the `width` and `min-width` properties of my option_ui html have no effect.

Can I specify an explicit value for the width of my options UI ?
In the docs, I have only found that it is possible to display this HTML [in its own page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/options_ui#Syntax), with the `open_in_tab` key in the manifest. This would give me full control over the way it is displayed. But since I have so few settings, I would prefer to display them inline.

Can I still influence their width ?

Here is a minimum example to reproduce the problem:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Settings example",
    "version": "1.0",
    "options_ui": {
      "page": "options.html"
    }
  }
```

**options.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body width='100px'>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tristique finibus ex, id posuere enim
        ultricies sed. Etiam elementum, mi sed euismod sagittis, neque ex vehicula enim, ut semper est mauris sit amet
        lorem. Nam porta semper lacus, a posuere est ullamcorper a. Integer dictum ante diam, a dictum ligula porttitor
        quis. Proin commodo venenatis ultrices. In at lacus sit amet diam laoreet facilisis. Donec vulputate, sapien
        vel semper elementum, nulla augue scelerisque tellus, ut fringilla lorem nisl non nulla.
    </p>
</body>

</html>
```

The `width` attribute in the body of my options html has no effect at all. Same for `min-width`.

Comment: oh sorry, I should have added that to the question. That's the first thing I tried: width and min-width on body. It is simply swallowed

Comment: well, you're double right. Sorry again, I should of course have included a minimal example. But that's fixed now :D

Comment: I don't think the `width` attribute is still supported on body. Use CSS: `body { min-width: 400px }` or an inline `style` attribute.

Comment: @wOxxOm embarrassingly, your comment fixes it. If you convert it to an answer, I'll accept it.